# How can I include Technotes when Searching a repository?

Tags: fossil

As I've been getting my feet wet with Fossil, I noticed the Search doesn't seem to return any matches in Technotes.

Is this by design, or should it be included in the 'Wiki' category? Or is there some hidden way to configure the search to include Technotes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This was added in [september 2017](https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/info/a551d503c290e545), and is supported since [release 2.4](https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/doc/trunk/www/changes.wiki#v2_4).

---

Looking at the [source code](https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/artifact?name=f8f9ec5bcd61107b&ln=697-775), searching the tech notes doesn't appear to be supported, currently.

I don't know whether the omission was intentional, or that the developer(s) simply forgot about the technotes (which has happened before).

You can ask the developers on the `fossil-users` mailing list: [read the archives here](https://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/), or [subscribe here](http://mailinglists.sqlite.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/fossil-users).

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that's good to know. I did try emailing fossil-users, but I don't think my email went through. I'll keep trying to get that working, thanks for the response, I appreciate it!